# Definir ordem das colunas no banco de dados usando SpringData

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, maven, spring-data

Gostaria de saber se é possível (se for, como fazer) definir a ordem das colunas no `banco de dados` utilizando `JPA`. notei que ele cria a coluna `Id` primeiro, e depois as colunas por ordem alfabética, como na imagem abaixo, porém gostaria de definir a ordenação da coluna (como por exemplo, a coluna Nome primeiro que a sobrenome), informando qual vem primeiro.

Imagem de exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma forma de ordenar, ele sempre cria em ordem alfabética. Como a tabela é gerenciada pelo próprio Hibernate, vc não teria que se importar com isso.

O que vc poderia fazer para contornar a situação seria criar o banco na mão ou nomear as colunas alfabeticamente para que elas fiquem na ordem que vc quer.

Caso opte por criar na mão, vc pode pegar o script de criação do banco com o seu SGBD e executá-lo com as colunas na ordenação que vc quer.

Eu particularmente recomendo que vc crie o seu banco com scripts separados

Comment: Valeu pela resposta @Gustavo